# Duplicate logging in GCP Logging Viewer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, google-cloud-platform, logback, spring-logback

I am using Spring MVC Java in the application and the logs are an output of the application hosted on GCP. The `logback.xml` is defined in consul. I am getting duplicate logs in the output of the application

```
[][]2020-02-09T19:14:43,675+07:00 WARN 
                c.g.s.b.s.spring.SessionInterceptor - Invalid session, let's create new session
[][]2020-02-09T19:14:43,675+07:00 WARN 
                c.g.s.b.s.spring.SessionInterceptor - Invalid session, let's create new session
10.0.27.1 - - [09/Feb/2020:19:14:43 +0700] "GET /mobile-api/sys-info/healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 83 0.092
[][]2020-02-09T19:14:53,668+07:00 WARN 
                c.g.s.b.s.spring.SessionInterceptor - Invalid session, let's create new session
[][]2020-02-09T19:14:53,668+07:00 WARN 
                c.g.s.b.s.spring.SessionInterceptor - Invalid session, let's create new session
10.0.27.1 - - [09/Feb/2020:19:14:53 +0700] "GET /mobile-api/sys-info/healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 83 0.083
[][]2020-02-09T19:15:03,656+07:00 WARN 
                c.g.s.b.s.spring.SessionInterceptor - Invalid session, let's create new session
[][]2020-02-09T19:15:03,656+07:00 WARN 
                c.g.s.b.s.spring.SessionInterceptor - Invalid session, let's create new session
10.0.27.1 - - [09/Feb/2020:19:15:03 +0700] "GET /mobile-api/sys-info/healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 83 0.088
[][]2020-02-09T19:15:13,661+07:00 WARN 
                c.g.s.b.s.spring.SessionInterceptor - Invalid session, let's create new session
[][]2020-02-09T19:15:13,661+07:00 WARN 
                c.g.s.b.s.spring.SessionInterceptor - Invalid session, let's create new session
```

Here is my configuration file: logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scanPeriod="1 minutes" scan="true">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%X{key}][%X{user}]%date{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX", Asia/Jakarta} %-5level
                %logger{35} - %replace(%msg){'\n', ' '}%nopex%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Try to set the "additivity" property as false - https://mkyong.com/logging/logback-duplicate-log-messages/

Comment: I am not using any logger to set the additivity flag to. Can we do it on root?

Answer (score 0):

Logging with Java Spring in GCP is covered in the official Spring webpage. In [11. Stackdriver Logging Support](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#stackdriver-logging). You need to add the corresponding dependencies mentioned in the page and change your logback.xml to:

```xml
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/cloud/gcp/logging/logback-appender.xml" />

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STACKDRIVER" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```